# Find the IP of the active NetworkInterface?

Tags: networking, ip-camera, onvif

I'm trying to figure out how to get, using ONVIF, the IP that the device is currently using. As an example, I have an IP camera which can be connected to the network using WiFi or Ethernet. The response to `GetNetworkInterfaces` looks like this (and it makes no difference if I plug or I unplug the network cable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:sc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">
  <s:Header/>
  <s:Body>
    <tds:GetNetworkInterfacesResponse>
      <tds:NetworkInterfaces token="eth0">
        <tt:Enabled>true</tt:Enabled>
        <tt:Info>
          <tt:Name>eth0</tt:Name>
          <tt:HwAddress>9c:8e:cd:03:00:85</tt:HwAddress>
          <tt:MTU>1500</tt:MTU>
        </tt:Info>
        <tt:Link>
          <tt:AdminSettings>
            <tt:AutoNegotiation>false</tt:AutoNegotiation>
            <tt:Speed>10</tt:Speed>
            <tt:Duplex>Full</tt:Duplex>
          </tt:AdminSettings>
          <tt:OperSettings>
            <tt:AutoNegotiation>false</tt:AutoNegotiation>
            <tt:Speed>10</tt:Speed>
            <tt:Duplex>Full</tt:Duplex>
          </tt:OperSettings>
          <tt:InterfaceType>6</tt:InterfaceType>
        </tt:Link>
        <tt:IPv4>
          <tt:Enabled>true</tt:Enabled>
          <tt:Config>
            <tt:Manual>
              <tt:Address>192.168.1.2</tt:Address>
              <tt:PrefixLength>24</tt:PrefixLength>
            </tt:Manual>
            <tt:DHCP>false</tt:DHCP>
          </tt:Config>
        </tt:IPv4>
        <tt:IPv6>
          <tt:Enabled>true</tt:Enabled>
          <tt:Config>
            <tt:AcceptRouterAdvert>false</tt:AcceptRouterAdvert>
            <tt:DHCP>Off</tt:DHCP>
            <tt:Manual>
              <tt:Address/>
              <tt:PrefixLength>0</tt:PrefixLength>
            </tt:Manual>
            <tt:LinkLocal>
              <tt:Address>fe80::9e8e:cdff:fe03:0085</tt:Address>
              <tt:PrefixLength>64</tt:PrefixLength>
            </tt:LinkLocal>
            <tt:FromRA>
              <tt:Address>2001:250:3000:3ca0:215:f2ff:fe5d:2301</tt:Address>
              <tt:PrefixLength>64</tt:PrefixLength>
            </tt:FromRA>
          </tt:Config>
        </tt:IPv6>
      </tds:NetworkInterfaces>
      <tds:NetworkInterfaces token="eth2">
        <tt:Enabled>true</tt:Enabled>
        <tt:Info>
          <tt:Name>eth2</tt:Name>
          <tt:HwAddress>9c:8e:cd:06:69:85</tt:HwAddress>
          <tt:MTU>1500</tt:MTU>
        </tt:Info>
        <tt:IPv4>
          <tt:Enabled>true</tt:Enabled>
          <tt:Config>
            <tt:FromDHCP>
              <tt:Address>192.168.1.15</tt:Address>
              <tt:PrefixLength>24</tt:PrefixLength>
            </tt:FromDHCP>
            <tt:DHCP>true</tt:DHCP>
          </tt:Config>
        </tt:IPv4>
        <tt:Extension>
          <tt:InterfaceType>71</tt:InterfaceType>
          <tt:Dot11>
            <tt:SSID>XXXXXX</tt:SSID>
            <tt:Mode>Extended</tt:Mode>
            <tt:Alias>Web_Default</tt:Alias>
            <tt:Priority>15</tt:Priority>
            <tt:Security>
              <tt:Mode>PSK</tt:Mode>
              <tt:Algorithm>TKIP</tt:Algorithm>
            </tt:Security>
          </tt:Dot11>
        </tt:Extension>
      </tds:NetworkInterfaces>
    </tds:GetNetworkInterfacesResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Is there a way to actually know which is the active network interface?

Comment: You can have multiple active network interfaces, and each of those interfaces could have multiple IPv4 and/or IPv6 addresses.

Comment: @RonMaupin how do I know which IPv4 and/or IPv6 address is active? What I mean, if I unplug the network cable, the eth0 is not active anymore and I couldn't find anything that shows me that.

Comment: All the addresses on an interface are active if the interface is up.

Comment: @RonMaupin I guess I'm not explaining clear enough: what's the current IP that the device is using right now to connect to the network? If the cable is unplugged, is not the 192.168.1.2 (eth0), it's 192.168.1.15 (eth2 - wifi), but how do I know this in code?

Comment: You are not understanding. All the addresses on all the interfaces that are up are active and could be used, depending on the destination address on the packet. The host has an internal routing table, and which address and interface are used for a packet is dictated by the routing table. Some packets could use one address on an interface, and other packets could use other addresses on the same or different interfaces. A device may not have a single active IP address.

Comment: In the case of IPv6, you are almost guaranteed to have multiple active addresses on each interface that is up. Every interface will have a link-local IPv6 address, and will probably have one or more global and/or ULA IPv6 addresses, and each gets used for different packets. There is even an RFC to explain which address should be used for which circumstances.

Comment: @RonMaupin eth0 means the ethernet port. If the cable is not plugged, that interface and the IP assigned cannot be used, right? I can ping 192.168.1.2 (eth0) until I unplug the cable ... and don't tell me that can be used after that... the router has no idea and can assign that IP to another device while the cable is is not connected. I understand that the device can have multiple "active" IPs, but when the cable is not connected, the one assigned to eth0 ain't one of them. Again, how do I know which IPs are active, aka I can connect to them to communicate with the device from outside.

Comment: I'm not talking about a router, I'm talking about the routing table inside the host that determines which source address and interface are use for an outbound packet. The routing table should reflect what interfaces are used.

Comment: @RonMaupin ... and the ONVIF way of finding that is?